# Gerrit: working with multiple branches & propagating changes

Tags: merge, branch, branching-and-merging, gerrit

I'm trying to identify the proper way of working with multiple branches on Gerrit that would match our workflow.

The way we work with branches right now is: we have master & feature branch. Master is the branch we want to polish and make it ready for release, while feature is obviously a field of intensive work. Now, in our particular case whenever somebody works on a bug fix, they:

- create a change targeted for master branch
- cherry pick it to the feature branch targeted change
- once gerrit code review completes, submit both changes.

now the way i understand cherry-pick, it selects individual commit and merges it to the current change. if that is the case, i would expect to have no merge conflicts in the end, and indeed this workflow works perfectly with just GIT. Gerrit, however, most likely due to its nature (branches are not merged remotely the way these are locally and get a different sha tag) lists a tremendous number of conflicting files in the end.

Now, I resolved all these issues by applying merge strategy (ours on feature, theirs on master), but it does not feel right: if anything was not propagated, it just got discarded.

My question is: is there a *safe* workflow, similar to the above one, that would in the end produce a clean merge with gerrit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that it's better, in this case, to merge than to cherry pick.

A cherry pick adds the same *changes* but not the same *commit*. So while the source is the same on a cherry pick and merge the *git tree* is different. When the tree is different and you later do a merge git will think that the commit you previously cherry picked is missing and try to merge that change as well, even if the actual code is already there. That's probably why you get a lot of conflicts.

I would propose another way of working.

- When you do normal work you develop on **feature** and push to Gerrit as normal.
- When you do a patch (ie bug fix) on the stable production environment you do that directly on **master**  (or local branches if you like but not on **feature**)
- When the patch as been approved in Gerrit it get's merged into the real **master** and you can make a *pull* request to get that change to your local copy. Your version of **master** is now the same as Gerrits **master**
- Now you would merge all new changes on **master** into **feature**. Make sure you do a *rebase* so that the patch ends up before anything you've already done on **feature**
- Once it's time to deploy all new features you can merge **feature** into **master**, push to Gerrit (if you have permissions you can by pass gerrit by pushing directly to **master** instead of refs/for/master as these changes are already reviewed)
- Once all changes are on Gerrits **master** you do a pull on your **master** and a merge into **feature** with *rebase* making **feature** a clean branch to work on. It's of course totally valid to have a new **feature** each release. Both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, as this flow should work just fine.  If other users submit changes before your bug fix is reviewed/verified/submitted, that could result in merge conflicts, but that should be rare.

If you:

1. Fix a bug on master
2. Push to review (creating change A in gerrit)
3. cherry-pick change A on top of the feature branch (resolving any conflicts from master to feature)
4. Push the cherry-picked change to review (creating change B)
5. Review/verify/submit changes A & B

Everything will work fine.  The only way for merge conflicts to occur is if other users upload and submit changes between steps 1 and 5.  Are you seeing different behavior?  Can you provide more details?

Comment: no, that's not the case. however there is a difference between what you said and what we do. the difference is: we usually cherry pick the changes before it's even pushed for review (so, locally). maybe that's the problem..?
thing is, some people get even approval before creating a cherry pick (large commits) and it still shows up as conflict. i believe it might turn out that we need to cherry-pick the submitted changes, not local branches..

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you cherry-pick before or after pushing to review.  I'm not sure what you mean by getting approval before creating a cherry-pick.

Comment: when you push changes to gerrit, these changes are not immediately merged. instead, they are candidates for a given branch, merged to these branches when you 'submit' your patchset. this means that the merge is not done in your local repository and it seems it also gets a separate SHA sum (i'm not too deep into gerrit details, so i don't know why it happens). i think the fact that there is no corelation between our cherry-picks and these remote sha sums, rebase / merge simply does not understand what goes on (it sees equivalent changes on both branches and treats them as conflicts)